# VBA returning a value from a sub

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word, return-value

I  basically want a survey document where the user selects a rating such as "always" and "never."  They select a rating by hitting a radio button.  The ratings are weighted and are averaged into a total score, like a GPA, i.e. always is worth 3, somewhat is worth 2 and each question should be added and then averaged. Below is a section of my code for one question.

How do I take the value at the end after the button is selected and average them for all the questions?

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then

        RadioButton3.Checked = False
        RadioButton2.Checked = False
        RadioButton4.Checked = False
        RadioButton5.Checked = False
        num1 = 2
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then

        RadioButton3.Checked = False
        RadioButton1.Checked = False
        RadioButton4.Checked = False
        RadioButton5.Checked = False
        num1 = 3
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then

        RadioButton1.Checked = False
        RadioButton2.Checked = False
        RadioButton4.Checked = False
        RadioButton5.Checked = False
        num1 = 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then

        RadioButton3.Checked = False
        RadioButton2.Checked = False
        RadioButton1.Checked = False
        RadioButton5.Checked = False
        num1 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.CheckedChanged


    If RadioButton5.Checked = True Then

        RadioButton3.Checked = False
        RadioButton2.Checked = False
        RadioButton4.Checked = False
        RadioButton1.Checked = False
        num1 = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would be better if you vote someone's answer .. :)

Comment: Sorry, new to this place

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can consolidate all of those RadioButton event handlers into ONE handler.  Furthermore, you don't have to "uncheck" the other RadioButtons in the group as this will be done automatically for you.  Finally, create a separate method that computes the rating and updates the form, then call that method at the bottom of the handler.

That might look something like this:

```
Private num1 As Integer

Private Sub set1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
        RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged, RadioButton3.CheckedChanged, _
        RadioButton4.CheckedChanged, RadioButton5.CheckedChanged

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        num1 = 2
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        num1 = 3
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked Then
        num1 = 1
    ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked Then
        num1 = 0
    ElseIf RadioButton5.Checked Then
        num1 = 0
    End If

    UpdateRating()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateRating()
    ' ... compute the rating using "num1", "num2", "num3", etc ...
    ' ... then update the GUI with the new value ...
End Sub
```

Note that all five RadioButtons are listed after the "Handles" keyword making them all fire the same handler.  You can do a similar thing for each group of RadioButtons...just make sure each set of RadioButtons is in its **OWN** container like a GroupBox or Panel.  A RadioButton is mutually exclusive with all other RadioButttons in its own **container**.

Comment: I tried this code but the radio buttons do not deselect when a different button is selected.  They all stay selected at once.  The UpdateRating() function was exactly what I needed however thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure all the RadioButtons are in the **same** container?

Comment: Got it figured out.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I actually copied my code from Visual Studios and used it in the build in Word macros and when I added the buttons, I changed the groups in properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about your case .. but you can try this

Declare your var that will count all result ..

```
Dim num1 as Integer 
Dim num2 as Integer '--> for other group radiobuttons
Dim num3 as Integer '--> for other group radiobuttons

Dim nTotal as Integer
Dim nAvg as Integer
```

Do this in **each** checkchanged

```
Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(..) Handles RadioButton1_CheckedChanged, RadioButton2_CheckedChanged,  .....

  'codes
  countit()

End Sub

Sub CountIt()
   nTotal = num1 + num2 + num3
   nAvg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3
End Sub
```